# Add nopcommerce shopping cart in mvc 4.0 razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, shopping-cart, nopcommerce

I am new in ASP.Net MVC and now I am trying to add a shopping cart in my project 'Online Shopping Management' which is my academic project using ASP.Net (MVC 4.0) . I download some shopping cart from web where 'nop-commerce' is one of them. Now anyone can tell me, in which process I can add this shopping-cart in my project using ASP.Net MVC 4.0 Razor engine ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start of with reading the requirements in which the following is a problem I see right away:

- ASP.NET 4.5 (MVC 5.0)
- Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 or above

Than I am not sure about using nop-commerce as a way to get a shopping card into your project. At least that is what I understand from your message.

I think you want to create your own shoppingcard. See following links:

online example and tutorial: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store

offline tutorial (PDF): http://docrepository.googlecode.com/files/MVC%20Music%20Store%20-%20Tutorial%20-%20v1.0.pdf

complete example (code and PDF): http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/releases/view/64379

Comment: Thanks...I saw this tutorial before your suggestion and I don't try this. But, from tomorrow night I work on it and now my project problems solved :D